# building a specific sequence with python numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy

Hi I have two arrays as below.

1) An array made up of 1 and 0. 1 Signifies that its an active day and 0 is a holiday.

2) An arithmetic sequence which is smaller in length compared to array 1.

The result array needs to be a combination of 1) & 2) wherein the arithmetic sequence needs to follow the positions of 1s. In other words the array 2 needs to expanded to array 1 length with 0s inserted in the same position as array 1.

One way i could solve this is using numpy.insert with slice. However, since the lengths are different and the array 1 is dynamic i need an efficient way to achieve this.

Thanks

[image: Final result]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative one-liner solution

**Setup**

```
binary = np.array([1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0])
arithmetic = np.arange(1, 7)
```

**Solution**

```
#find 1s from binary and set values from arithmetic
binary[np.where(binary>0)] = arithmetic

Out[400]: array([1, 2, 0, 3, 0, 4, 5, 0, 6, 0])
```

Answer (score 1):

Create the result array of the right length (`len(binary)`) filled with 0s, then use the `binary` array as a mask to assign into the result array. Make sure the `binary` mask is of the `bool` dtype.

```
>>> binary = np.array([1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0], dtype=bool)
>>> arithmetic = np.arange(1, 7)
>>> result = np.zeros(len(binary), dtype=arithmetic.dtype)
>>> result[binary] = arithmetic
>>> result
array([1, 2, 0, 3, 0, 4, 5, 0, 6, 0])
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be to create a copy of binary array and replace all non-zero values by arithmatic array

```
seq = np.arange(1, len(bi_arr[bi_arr != 0])+1)

final_result = bi_arr.copy()

final_result[final_result != 0] = seq
```

print(final_result)

```
array([1, 2, 0, 3, 0, 4, 5, 0, 6, 0])
```

The bi-arr remains unchanged